# Deep-learning device that supports Windows 7

Tags: windows

I'm experimenting with neural networks, and I'd like to buy one of these devices like the [Intel's Neural Compute Stick 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KT6361R) or [Google's Coral Edge Accelerator](https://coral.ai/products/accelerator/). However, I'm using Windows 7, and it seems that both of these devices require either Windows 10 or Linux or Mac. I don't want to upgrade to Windows 10.

**Are you familiar with a similar product that supports Windows 7?** It doesn't have to be as powerful as these two, as long as it's faster than using the CPU.